# Can't install Simple Windows Service - Login?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to create a simple Windows Service based on [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx). When I try to execute the command:

```
C:\worl\Project Alpha\Code\AlphaBackendService\AlphaBackendService\bin\Debug>ins
tallutil.exe AlphaBackendService.exe
```

It presents a dialog box with username, Password, Confirm password. Nothing I enter works and the install fails. What account does it want? Why can't I just use anything I type in? IIs it because of the EventLog requiring permission:

```
 public partial class AlphaBackendService : ServiceBase
 {
        public AlphaBackendService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("AlphaSource"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("AlphaSource", "AlphaLog");
            }
            eventLog1.Source = "AlphaSource";
            eventLog1.Log = "AlphaLog";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStop");
        }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: are you an admin on the machine?  can you run elevated?  if not, that's your problem

Comment: I am Admin on my machine and I am running the command in an elevated dev command console

Comment: are you positive?  can you provide screen shot of the dialog box?

Comment: I saw this in the log: An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

Comment: Is this machine on the NT domain?

Comment: No, it's a Windows 8 machine logged into with my Windows Live account which I just confirmed is an Admin account. The command is also issued from an admin dev console

Comment: I only got that exception because I tried entering my Windows Live accont in the dialog box but I should not even be getting the dialog box

Comment: I've done that many times, if that is a stand-alone machine it must be permissions issue, you don't have admin rights or are not running Installutil.exe under the accounts that has admin rights...

Comment: based on the exception it's possible your profile is corrupt, you can create a new admin account and try elevating with that account, if that works you can simply delete and recreate your current account.  If it doesn't work you probably have some misconfiguration on your system, and may have better luck at it on superuser.com

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the ProjectInstaller, set the propery Account to LocalSystem (From designer) or set following code in InitializeComponent() method

```
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
```

Comment: "ProjectInstaller.cs" should be in the same folder as the project/service (Adding the comment since it took me a couple of minutes to find it) :)